# Vertex and egde not stick to outline of circle mesh

Tags: vertices, edges

I have follow a tutorial but my circle vertices and edges are not stick to the outline of circle

my own pic:
[image]

tutorial pic
[image]

I know this is basic problem but I need help thank you

[image]

Comment: It's because you are using a _Subdivision Surface_ modifier. Blender averages (rounds out) the angles between adjoining faces in order to place new vertices for the modifier, which usually results in the (modified) mesh "shrinking" a little bit relative to the original geometry.

Comment: thank you for telling me, I appreciate your help